# WriteStream is not able to write Data in Delta Table

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am trying to connect Streaming Json files from the streaming path using the below code

```
Schema1= "customerId STRING,orderId STRING,products ARRAY<STRUCT<productId: STRING,quantity: STRING,soldPrice: STRING>>,salesRepId STRING,shippingAddress STRUCT<address: STRING,attention: String,city: STRING,state: STRING,zip: STRING>,submittedAt TIMESTAMP";
streamingDF = (spark.readStream.schema(Schema1)\
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json(stream_path))
```

After few transformations in streamingDF  Streaming Dataset and trying to write to a Delta Table using below code

```
streamingDF.writeStream.outputMode("append")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", orders_checkpoint_path)\
  .partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm")\
  .table("sachin")
```

But those records are not inserted into our delta table and also when I checked the dashboard it shows that numInputRows is 0

[Screenshot of streaming while writestream being executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXYCa.png)

Why those records are not append into delta table?

Comment: according to the graph, you didn't have any input data

Comment: Try to delete  the checkpoint folder and run it again. ```dbutils.fs.rm(orders_checkpoint_path, True) ```

Comment: yes it will work when we run it back after deleting the checkpoint path

Answer (score 2):

instead of using .table() use .start() then path the table path instead of the table name:

```
   streamingDF.writeStream.outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", orders_checkpoint_path)
  .partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm")
  .start("/pathtotable/sachin")
```