# Spark Structured Streaming rate limit

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am Trying to control records per triggers in structured streaming. Is their any function for it. I tried different properties but nothing seems to be working.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

val checkpointPath = "/user/akash-singh.bisht@unilever.com/dbacademy/developer-foundations-capstone/checkpoint/orders"
// val outputPath = "/user/akash-singh.bisht@unilever.com/dbacademy/developer-foundations-capstone/raw/orders/stream"

val devicesQuery = df.writeStream
                     .outputMode("append")
                     .format("delta")
                     .queryName("orders")
                     .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 second"))
                     .option("inputRowsPerSecond", 1)
                     .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
//                   .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
//                   .start(orders_checkpoint_path)
                     .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointPath)
                     .table("orders")
```

Comment: what is the streaming source in your case?

Comment: Its JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta uses two options `maxFilesPerTrigger` & `maxBytesPerTrigger`. You already use the first one, and it takes over the precedence over the second. The real number of records processed per trigger depends on the size of the input files and number of records inside it, as Delta processes complete files, not splitting it into multiple chunks.

But these options needs to be specified on the [source Delta table](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#delta-table-as-a-stream-source), not on the sink, as you specify right now:

```scala
spark.readStream.format("delta")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "1")
  .load("/delta/events")
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "...")
  .table("orders")
```

Update, just to show that option works.

Generate test data in directory `/Users/user/tmp/abc/`:

```sh
for i in {1..100}; do echo "{\"id\":$i}" > $i.json; done
```

then run the test, but use `foreachBatch` to map what file was processed in which trigger/batch:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.readStream.format("json").schema("id int") \
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "1").load("/Users/user/tmp/abc/")
df2 = df.withColumn("file", F.input_file_name())

def feb(d, e):
  d.withColumn("batch", F.lit(e)).write.format("parquet") \
    .mode("append").save("2.parquet")
stream = df2.writeStream.outputMode("append").foreachBatch(feb).start()
# wait a minute or so
stream.stop()

bdf = spark.read.parquet("2.parquet")
# check content
>>> bdf.show(5, truncate=False)
+---+----------------------------------+-----+
|id |file                              |batch|
+---+----------------------------------+-----+
|100|file:///Users/user/tmp/abc/100.json|94   |
|99 |file:///Users/user/tmp/abc/99.json |19   |
|78 |file:///Users/user/tmp/abc/78.json |87   |
|81 |file:///Users/user/tmp/abc/81.json |89   |
|34 |file:///Users/user/tmp/abc/34.json |69   |
+---+----------------------------------+-----+

# check that each file came in a separate batch
>>> bdf.select("batch").dropDuplicates().count()
100
```

If I increase `maxFilesPerTrigger` to 2, then I'll get 50 batches, etc.

Comment: On the source? Please clarify with code.

Comment: Yes  I tried by applying at source also . but it isn't working .

Comment: see updated post that demonstrate that trigger works

Comment: Alex you are amazing . probably i found the answer from the other question where u answered it . thanks .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469385/writestream-is-not-able-to-write-data-in-delta-table  . your solution worked for me too.

Comment: Interesting did not realize that. What is files with just an update? Is for the databricks platform only or als just using delta api on hdp, say?

Comment: Updated files aren't considered for reprocessing - it's standard behaviour of Spark. If you perform update on Delta, then by default consumption will fail until you have `ignoreChanges` (https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#ignore-updates-and-deletes) it's the same for Delta on Databricks & OSS

Comment: Thx i will try out soon. Thx. Big answer for sure.